# Aggregating 15-minute data into weekly values

Tags: sql, database, aggregate

I'm currently working on a project in which I want to aggregate data (resolution = 15 minutes) to weekly values.

I have 4 weeks and the view should include a value for each week AND every station.
My dataset includes more than 50 station.

What I have is this:

```
select name, avg(parameter1), avg(parameter2)  
from data  
where week in ('29','30','31','32')  
group by name  
order by name
```

But it only displays the avg value of all weeks. What I need is avg values for each week and each station.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do a 'GROUP BY' on just name you then flatten the weeks and you can only perform aggregate functions on them.

Your best option is to do a GROUP BY on both name and week so something like:

```
select name, week, avg(parameter1), avg(parameter2)
from data
where week in ('29','30','31','32')
group by name, week
order by name
```

PS - It' not entirely clear whether you're suggesting that you need one set of results for stations and one for weeks, or whether you need a set of results for every week at every station (which this answer provides the solution for). If you require the former then separate queries are the way to go.

Comment: Depending on the requirements, it may be proper to order by WEEK and NAME, but fundamentally I believe this is the correct answer.